# phpMyAdmin not working After Fresh install with apache2

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

when i try to access the phpmyadmin page i receive the following error:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
use PhpMyAdmin\Routing;
if (! defined('ROOT_PATH')) {
    // phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects
    define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    // phpcs:enable
}
global $route, $containerBuilder;
require_once ROOT_PATH . 'libraries/common.inc.php';
$dispatcher = Routing::getDispatcher();
Routing::callControllerForRoute($route, $dispatcher, $containerBuilder);
```

couldn't find a solution to this on any pixel of the internet, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your post does not include the error that you mention. Please edit your question and include the error message

Comment: The error is a blank page with the code i wrote, there isn't much i can add

Comment: It seems like your system doesn't have a working PHP installation. Which operating system do you have and how have you installed Apache? Did you install and configure any PHP interpreter?

Comment: Hi @IsaacBennetch yes i have apache installed, but i don't remember about "PHP Interpreter" i'll research about it.

Comment: How have you installed Apache? Do you use a package manager, did you compile it from source, etc?

Comment: Installed using:
apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-perl2

Comment: You should install a PHP interpreter with something like `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php`. There are some other library pacakges like `php-gd` or`php-mbstring` that you might need, but they might be pulled in automatically when you install libapache2-mod-php, so give that a try and let me know what happens next.

Answer (score 28):

I was facing the same problem but solved it through the below command

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php8.1

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to remove my php with `apt-get --purge remove php-common` and download it back with `apt-get install php7.4 php7.4-mysqli php7.4-xml` followed by `systemctl reload apache2` to restart apache.

If the above does not work, I recommend you to re-download phpmyadmin

Comment: `apt-get install php8.1 php8.1-mysql php8.1-xml` for php 8.1 (I also needed to reinstall phpmyadmin, after that it worked like a charm...)

Comment: I gotta admit it! its a very good answer!
when phpmyadmin reacts like that its definetely because it is missing php-*-mysql and xml in it.
good job guys

Answer (score 2):

## Step 1 – Install Apache and PHP

```
$ sudo apt install apache2 wget unzip 
$ sudo apt install php php-zip php-json php-mbstring php-mysql
```

Once the installation is finished, enable and start the Apache web server.

```
$ sudo systemctl enable apache2 
$ sudo systemctl start apache2
```

## Step 2 – Install phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 22.04

```
$ wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/5.2.0/phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-all-languages.zip 
$ unzip phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-all-languages.zip 
$ sudo mv phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-all-languages /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Next, create tmp directory and set the proper permissions. This is a necessary step to make it work properly.

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp 
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/phpmyadmin 
$ sudo chmod 777 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp
```

## Step 3 – Configure phpMyAdmin

Now, you need to configure the web server to serve phpMyAdmin on the network. Create an Apache configuration file for phpMyAdmin and edit it in a text editor:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
```

#### Add the below content to the file.###

```html
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
 
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      <RequireAny>
      Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
 
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     <RequireAny>
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

After making all the changes, make sure to start the Apache service to reload all settings.

```
$ sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin 
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

## Step 4 – Adjusting FirewallD

The systems with enabled firewalls need to allow HTTP service from the firewall. Run the below commands to open a port for the webserver in the firewall.

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http 
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

If you don't have firewall installed, run:

```
$ sudo apt-get firewall
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work. credit gose to MoonE.

```
# install the required modules
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
# enable php in apache2, type the name of the module from the list of available modules
sudo a2enmod
# reload apache for the changed config to take effect.
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see php code in your browser it means that the PHP interpreter wasn't used. This means the problem is not with PhpMyAdmin but with your php installation. I googled quickly  [this](https://kinsta.com/blog/install-php/) but you (or others) may find better tutorials.

When new to apache php and mysql/mariadb I recommend installing [wampserver](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=english) or [mamp](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/). They do take all the hard configuration work from you.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, but PHP was installed and running.  Restarting Apache fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
sudo a2enmod php8.1
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

This mean php intepreter is not installed.
To solve this, do :

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

Answer (score -1):

```bash
sudo a2enmod php8.2
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on how the proposed solution solves the problem and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.